# Does the ntfs-3g driver still corrupt disks/files/folders?

Tags: ntfs-3g

As I said in the title, does the ntfs-3g driver still corrupt disks/files/folders on ntfs disks? I have heard a lot of people having problems with the driver. Is that still the case, or have the developers "fixed" the driver?

Answer (score 2):

No. If such cases still happen they are documented already. Remember that the ntfs-3g driver is mostly a reverse engineering effort to make NTFS partitions readable and writeable in Linux-based OS's.

There's a list of known issues [in the Tuxera support page.](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/)